# Representation of an Abelian Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I have to do this exercise:

> Given an abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ on an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$. Let
>   $
> \varphi : \mathfrak{h} \to \text{End}_{\mathbb{F}}(V)
> $
>   be a representation over the finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$. For every $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*= \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{F}}(\mathfrak{h}, \mathbb{F})$ define
>   \begin{gather}
> V_\lambda =\{ v \in V | \varphi(h)v=\lambda(h)v, \forall h\in \mathfrak{h} \}
> \end{gather}
>   Prove that $V= \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*}V_\lambda$.

I think that this statement isn't true, indeed pick 
\begin{gather}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
and let $\mathfrak{h}=\langle A \rangle$ be the set of all $cA$ with $c \in \mathbb{F}$, then $\mathfrak{h}$ acts naturally on $\mathbb{F}$ and the existence of such a decomposition would imply that $A$ is diagonalizable, which isn't.
Am I right?

Comment: What exactly is your $\mathfrak{h}$? Don't you mean $0,x; 0,0$? In any case, some additional assumption must be made on the representation, as you see.

Comment: ok, good precisation, for $\mathfrak{h}$ i mean all scalar multiples of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such decomposition of $V$ into weight spaces $V_\lambda$ is a possible under some additional assumption. For example, it holds if $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, but in this case, there is no such semisimple $\mathfrak{g}$. Indeed, the canonic representation $F^2$ (if this is what you mean) of your $\mathfrak{h}$ is not completely reducible.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you mean by "such theorems"? If you replace $\mathfrak{h}$ by a semisimple Lie algebra, the statement is still not true (it holds for the Cartan subalgebra of a semisimple Lie algebra).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Right. Is it better now?

Comment: Yeah, though I must say I wonder what the original exercise was supposed to be (possibly it wanted the Lie algebra to consist of diagonalizable elements with respect to the given representation).